# Flex-direction: reverse column hides navigation component

Tags: html, css, reactjs

**PROBLEM:** `<Navigation/>` components **disappears** when I use `flex-direction: column-reverse`

However, when I use `flex-direction: column`, the component renders at the top of the screen and **is visible**.

My goal is to render my `<Navigation/>` component as bottom navigation bar, similar to an iPhone app.

Here is my code:

```js
<div className="app">
      <Router>
        <div className="navigation__wrapper">
          <Navigation />
        </div>
        <div className="route__wrapper">
          <AppWrapper>
            <Switch>
              <Route
                exact
                path="/"
                render={() => (
                  <MainLayout>
                    <Homepage />
                  </MainLayout>
                )}
              />

            
            </Switch>
          </AppWrapper>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </div>
```

Here is my css:

```css
.app {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  background-color: var(--main-background);
  font-family: "Poppins";
  max-width: 100vw;
  min-width: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flex-direction: column-reverse doesn't only reverse the order of the column, but also the placement. E.g., if align-items and justify-content are both set to flex-start (as is their initial value) and your flex items don't have a combined height at least as big as the flexbox container, they'll all move to the bottom left corner instead of staying at the top left like you might expect. You can fix this like below...

```
.app {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  background-color: var(--main-background);
  font-family: "Poppins";
  max-width: 100vw;
  min-width: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Alternatively, you could just keep flex-direction: column and move the div holding the navigation down to below route__wrapper.

Not to sell myself here, but I made a web app that might help you with understanding Flexbox. Link: https://csspressme.web.app/playbox/flexbox

Also, I'm not sure that this helps you entirely without seeing all of your code.

Comment: This is awesome, David! Love the web app